# Handling Social Media Integrations in a MEAN stack App after a user is Logged in

Tags: node.js, angular, callback, passport.js, mean-stack

A user can create an account in my App only with his work email.

Example: `john@xyzcompany.com`

After he creates an account, he can link multiple social media accounts to his profile.

Example: `john@gmail.com`, `john2@gmail.com`

I'm using MEAN stack to develop the App.

When a user logs in to my app, I'm creating a JWT token to authorize all his future requests to the server.

When it comes to Social Media accounts Integrations, After successful authentication I'm able to receive the accessTokens from these Social Media to the backend callback URL. I need to link the tokens to the right user. Is there anyway I can pass my JWT token along with the callback URL to identify which user has made the request, because I cannot identify the user based on the email in his Social Media Account?

I was able to solve this using `socket.io`. But I feel it is unnecessary to use sockets for simple authentication.

Is there any other approach to solve it? I have researched online, few of them suggested using passport. I don't fully understand how passport works, I just feel it is just a middleware to authenticate API requests from users, which I'm doing anyway using a custom function.

Could someone explain whether it is possible to pass JWT in callback URLs using passport strategies?

What is the right approach to handle such authentications in a MEAN stack app? I'm stuck with this issue since the past week, really looking forward for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this type of situation in one of the large scale applications I have been working for and the approach we used to handle it was to store the jwtToken in redis and then retrieve it back with the help of user cookies. Let me explain it in more detail -

1. Send a new Cookie for the user when the user opens the login page. The cookie should contain some unique id or code against which we will save the JWT token,. Eg: `res.cookie('jwtIdentifier', newid())`
2. Now, when the user logs in, generate the JWT token and save it to your redis against the cookie jwtIdentifier's value. Eg: `redisHelper.set(req.cookies.jwtIdentifier, JWTTOKEN)`
3. At last, when the login is successful and the user is redirected back to your app, you can retrieve your JWT token again for the corresponding user using the cookie. Eg: `redisHelper.get(req.cookies.jwtIdentifier)` This will give you back the JWT token that you can then use across your application for that specific user.

Hope it's clear, let me know if you have any questions with this implementation ;)

Comment: `JWT` token management for user API requests is what I have already done. I'm looking for a solution to handle callbacks from Social Media at the backend.

Comment: I didn't meant that. The thing you mentioned is you want to identify the user from which the request is coming after logging in so that you can use the appropriate token for further requests in your app. Right? If this is it, I think the way I explained above should work

Answer (score 0):

You might try using client side facebook authentication as described here

https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/facebook-login-angular-rest-api/

in this case in angular app you have facebook token alongside your app token and you can send them to your backend to identify the current user.

on backend part you eill call facebook to get profile data from accessToken and then store user profile id and depending on your business you might need also to store the access token